# Best solution for storing 10,000,000+ lines of json objects which needs to be checked (new data inserted) daily

Tags: sql, json, database, nosql, bigdata

I have a big zip file which contains around 10,000,000+ lines of json objects. Every day I receive a new zip file which contains mostly exactly the same data but some of it (maybe around 2%) is different - a few json properties have changed etc. I need to store the data efficiently and it needs to **provide fast reads**. The application users themselves don't write to the database, but perform reads only.

As I said I receive new data daily and most of it is exactly the same, but some of it differs. Another caveat is that some of the data is in different order. **I need to update the database with the new data, but discard the data which is the same**. Example:

```json
{"address": "123 Main St", "organization": "Real Estate Co", "building": {"type": "House", "leased": false}, "residents": [{"name": "John Doe", "age": 30}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 28}], "facilities": ["Garden"], "location": {"city": "Metropolis", "country": "US"}, "risks": ["Burglary"]}
{"address": "456 Oak St", "organization": "Urban Apartments", "building": {"type": "Apartment", "leased": true}, "residents": [{"name": "Alice Smith", "age": 25}, {"name": "Bob Johnson", "age": 30}], "facilities": ["Fitness Center", "Swimming Pool"], "location": {"city": "Downtownville", "country": "US"}, "risks": ["Noise Complaints", "Fire Hazard"]}
```

*The sample data here is not the real data which I'm dealing with but is quite similar. The `address` property in my data actually unique.*

and for example if the data I receive tomorrow contains the following data:

```json
{"address": "123 Main St", "organization": "Real Estate Co", "building": {"type": "House", "leased": false}, "residents": [{"name": "John Doe", "age": 30}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 28}], "facilities": ["Garden"], "location": {"city": "Metropolis", "country": "US"}, "risks": ["Burglary"]}
{"address": "456 Oak St", "organization": "Urban Apartments", "building": {"type": "Apartment", "leased": false}, "residents": [{"name": "Alice Smith", "age": 25}, {"name": "Bob Johnson", "age": 30}], "facilities": ["Fitness Center", "Swimming Pool", "Burger Shop", "Basketball court"], "location": {"city": "Downtownville", "country": "US"}, "risks": ["Noise Complaints", "Fire Hazard"]}
```

then I would need to store the **second** json object because it's **different from the yesterday's json object** (**NOTE**: the 'unique' address is still the same but it has different properties).

---

The optimal solution to which I came up to is to store the data in one database table, and to create a composite key which consists of the unique `address` and automatically generated `Date`. So the sample data looks like this.
(*MongoDB example*):

```json
{"_id":{"address":"123 Main St","date":"06-01-2024"},"organization":"ABC Inc","as":{"number":12345,"organization":"Internet Services Ltd"},"client":{},"tunnels":[{"operator":"PROXY_OPERATOR","type":"VPN","anonymous":false}],"location":{"city":"Metropolis","country":"US"},"risks":["DATA_LEAK"]}
```

(*MySQL example*):

```sql
address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL,
    address_data JSON NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (address, date)
```

And it would do a check whether the data is unique (not taking into account the `date` field) and then perform an insertion (not update) to the table.

So in a nutshell, every day I receive a new zip file which contains around 10 million lines of json data. I need to add new data to the database and discard the rest of it.

**What I tried?**

At first I tried to use MySQL database, which I ran using Docker. I created a table schema like this:

```sql
address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL,
    address_data JSON NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (address, date)
```

Then I used the `LOAD DATA` command for bulk insertion:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/data.json'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@json)
SET address = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.address')),
    date = CURRENT_DATE,
    address_data = @json;
```

But with this some issues arouse, namely as per MySQL docs:
`It is not possible to load data files that use the ucs2, utf16, utf16le, or utf32 character set.`

Some of the data contains characters of these character sets or unicode escapes that MySQL doesn't like which results in data insertion errors.
`ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 86.`

After some headaches I figured why not to use a MongoDB instead, as it should store the json object more effectively.
Modified the data with `jq`, like this:

```bash
jq -c '. + { "_id": { "address": .address, "date": (now | strftime("%d-%m-%Y")) } }' data.json > formatted_data.json
```

To receive this:

```json
{"_id":{"address":"123 Main St","date":"06-01-2024"},"organization": "Real Estate Co", "building": {"type": "House", "leased": false}, "residents": [{"name": "John Doe", "age": 30}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 28}], "facilities": ["Garden"], "location": {"city": "Metropolis", "country": "US"}, "risks": ["Burglary"]}
```

I used the [mongoimport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongoimport) command which inserted all the data successfully but now the issue is how can I insert the new data in bulk? As far as I know this is not possible with `mongoimport` as it doesn't support conditional operations. Some options are to use python or something to compare the data and add new but this can take quite a while

Comment: generate db update commands from a json diff patch or merge patch tool?

Comment: Recommending tools/software is off-topic for this forum, as is anything opinion-based, so unless you have a specific code-related issue then it's difficult to help you. The one point I would make is that processing 10M+ records every day, when only a few have changed, is incredibly inefficient. I would therefore focus on your source system providing a delta file, if at all possible